# VB.net - Error When Sending email using smtpclient

Tags: .net, vb.net, smtp, smtpclient

```
Dim MailBody1 As String = vbCrLf & "A new carrier tape (Part Number: " & code & ") has been added into the system. Please verify and buy-off the specs in the MRP system. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "MRP System: " & tsURL & vbCrLf & "Module: Manufacturing --> First Article --> QA"
Dim MailClient1 = New SmtpClient("localhost")
MailClient1.send(MailFrom1, MailTo1, MailSubject1, MailBody1)
'Catch ex As Exception
'End Try
```

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail
>   address.

this is the error it shows. Before that it work perfectly. Anyone help?

Full function code here

```
Public Sub send_email(ByVal code)
    Dim tsURL As String = "http://orion/one/"
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim email_add As String

    conn1("SELECT * FROM hr_employee WHERE emp_position IN ('QA ENGINEER', 'SR. QA ENGINEER') AND status = 'employed'", "email_add")
    If ds.Tables("email_add").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For n = 0 To ds.Tables("email_add").Rows.Count - 1
            dr = ds.Tables("email_add").Rows(n)
            If n <> ds.Tables("email_add").Rows.Count - 1 Then
                email_add = email_add + dr("email")
                email_add = email_add + ", "
            Else
                email_add = email_add + dr("email")
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'Try
    Dim MailFrom1 As String = "ts_admin@astigp.com"
    'Dim MailTo1 As String = "tancheekeong@astigp.com, keesoonwei@astigp.com, karentan@astigp.com"
    Dim MailTo1 As String = email_add
    Dim MailSubject1 As String = "New Carrier Tape : " & code
    Dim MailBody1 As String = vbCrLf & "A new carrier tape (Part Number: " & code & ") has been added into the system. Please verify and buy-off the specs in the MRP system. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "MRP System: " & tsURL & vbCrLf & "Module: Manufacturing --> First Article --> QA"
    Dim MailClient1 = New SmtpClient("localhost")
    MailClient1.send(MailFrom1, MailTo1, MailSubject1, MailBody1)
    'Catch ex As Exception
    'End Try
```

Comment: The error message was clear. Check value of `MailFrom1` and `MailTo1`, they may contain invalid mail address.

Comment: The value are correct.

Comment: As i check just now
on database is nvarchar for the `email_add`
why am i get that wrong?
And as u can see i had convert it to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your MailTo1 has invalid email address in it.
Maybe try to remove the space after the comma.

e.g. email_add = email_add + ","

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method of sending a mail using SmtpClient

```
   Try
                Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
                Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
                Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password")
                Smtp_Server.Port = 587
                Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
                Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

                e_mail = New MailMessage()
                e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtemail.Text)
                e_mail.To.Add(txtemail.Text)
                e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
                e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
                e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
                Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
                MsgBox("Mail Sent")

            Catch error_t As Exception
                MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
            End Try
```